# What is the correct part of speech when someone calls you by your name?

Tags: parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis, grammatical-roles

If someone uses your name in all correspondence with you, and this is not necessary, then what part of the English language is the name?

For example:

> What is your point **Jay**?

Comment: The **addressee**? You ask for "part of speech" but it is unclear whether your question refers to the unnecessary habit you mention. It's not strictly unnecessary anyway, we use the person's name in face to face talk too, when we want to emphasise something.

Comment: I would add **familiar**. A letter or email becomes more personal if the recipient's name is used in its text. Similarly when talking, we use the person's name to draw them in closer, or sometimes, to lessen the assault if an admonishment is coming next, to let them know you still love them.

Answer (score 3):

The part of speech for people's names is:

> [a proper noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun) or proper name

They act grammatically mostly like other nouns (common nouns) but with some minor differences.

Comment: Perhaps add the differences. Capitalization I believe is one.

Answer (score 2):

Stating the addressee in a sentence is called **direct address**.
It should be punctuated like an adverbial phrase.  Your example should be punctuated with a comma: "What is your point, Jay?"

This is also known as a [vocative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case).

Answer (score 0):

> What is your point Jay?

In the sentence, which requires a comma before "Jay", "Jay" is a **vocative**

OED

> Vocative (n.)
> **1.Grammar. ... (as a count noun) a word in the vocative case, or the vocative form of a word. Later also in uninflected languages (such as
> modern English): a word or phrase being used as a form of address..**
>
> 1987 Some of us use the vocatives ‘dear boy’, ‘dear girl’, and ‘old
> thing’ more than seems necessary to those who have good memories for
> names. *Times (Nexis) 20 April*
>
> 2013 The most famous vocative in Latin, Julius Caesar's ‘Et tu,
> Brute’.
> *H. Eyres, Horace & Me xiv. 227*

Comment: Hmph. I know nounification is an old thing, but it really grates here.